# What's the Gibbs free energy of a reaction at zero temperature and pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

I heard that Gibbs free energy changes with temperature and pressure as

$$ \Delta G_1 = \Delta G_0 + R T \ln Q $$

But this makes no sense when pressure is zero or temperature is zero.

Comment: How so? What's the problem with T=0?

Comment: [The guy's name was Gibbs, not Gibb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs)

Comment: It makes no sense of either of them odd zero. Pressure can never be zero and neither do temperature.

Comment: If the temperature is absolute zero, how is anything going to move to react? If the pressure is absolute zero, then you don't have a molecule in your volume to do any reactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$G^\circ = U(0K) = E^{ele}+ZPE$, i.e. the sum of the electronic energy (electrons and nuclei interacting) and the zero point vibrational energy.

You can't use $K=e^{-\Delta G^\circ/RT}$ at 0K because the derivation assumes that a certain amount of thermal energy is available. But you don't need the equation to figure out the relative amount of two molecules. At equilibrium at 0K *all* molecules are in the lowest possible state.